How can extract the content from image using python with the pytesseract?
I tried to extract the content from an image with the Python py-tesseract OCR, but I was unable to obtain the numbers. I get the extracted_text empty value.

Code:
def ImageReader(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
    extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config='--psm 7')
    print("Extract text" + extracted_text.strip())
    return extracted_text.strip()


nice try but you should pre-process the image... otherwise solving captcha would be very easy. Check the doc and some tutorial

"duplicate"

@cards, I checked as suggested, but I'm getting the text, it should be getting the number.
